# Typescript: Argument type string[] is not assignable to parameter type any

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

There is a point I don't understand, in an angular application. Here is my piece of code:

```
expect(routeurSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: 'index' } });
```

The error `Argument type string[] is not assignable to parameter type any` appears for both arguments of the `toHaveBeenCalledWith` method.

I can understand that any cannot be cast to string[], but why can't an array be casted to any?

Note that I could cast explicitely to any, e.g.

```
expect(routeurSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['login'] as any, { queryParams: { returnUrl: 'index' } } as any);
```

But I then have a tslint error because of the no-any rule.
And before disabling this rule, I'd like to understand why there is such an error?

Comment: Are you linting a test file? Normally, you wouldn't do this. I believe this is happening because `['login']` is already defined explicitly as an array of strings; this theory can be validated by setting a variable above to this, then passing in the var. so `const val:any = ['login'];`

Comment: This is a weird error since `any` should be assignable both to and from `string[]`.  I would love to be able to see this myself.  Consider providing a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) or a link to your project in an existing web IDE.  Without it I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: After looking deeper, this is only an intellij error as it compiles / tests / lints successfully. I turned to inspection rule "type mismatch" to warning only. Any if you want to have a look, this is on https://github.com/rolintoucour/ng-intellij-type-mismatch . I will post it to intellij too.